# Rotate the storyboard window in xcode 5

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

How to rotate the storyboard view controller into landscape, I can't find the orientation in the **Attributes Inspector**, is there anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simple, when you know how:

1. Select the View Controller you want to review in Landscape
2. In the `Attributes Inspector` look at the `Simulated Metrics` section (at the top)
3. Under `Orientation` select `Landscape`

If you are using `Inferred` then rotating your Root ViewController will rotate all the view controllers connected by segues.

Comment: Thanks! It was hidden!